# Eclipse Annoying Default Formatting

Tags: android, eclipse, formatting

My original code:

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

Code after format (annoying!):

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

What setting do I adjust to prevent eclipse's format from making this particular change?  I'm looking in the formatter settings, but haven't been able to find it yet as I'm not quite sure how I would describe this change...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to avoid the line wrapping is to increase the value of field "Maximum line width" on the "Line Wrapping" tab of `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit...`

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful for some other annoying formatting that was being done, but for my particular question, it was not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what I actually wanted was...

`Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Line Wrapping > Function Calls`, then to set the `Line wrapping policy` to `Do not wrap (5 of 5)`.

Comment: That's another way of disabling the line wrapping of function calls. It wasn't clear from your question whether you wanted to disable the wrapping of function calls at all times or not.